# phpDesigner 8 font rendering bug

Tags: ide, phpdesigner

phpDesigner 8 seems to have an error rendering text. I'm comparing it to **Sublime Text 2**.

Using these values:

[image]

in both programs, I get these different results:

[image]
[image]

Seems like **phpDesigner 8** is *expanding* the font, but I can't find any configuration which allows me to stop that behavior.

How can I remove the horizontal font extra space?

Comment: I was trying the evaluation version, and the very first thing I did when I loaded it up was change the font and found its broken with every font I tried.  I wrote an email to support.  They said "Use the default font."  Pitiful.  What kind of editor doesn't render basic fonts right?  Highly disgusted by this.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you had this problem resolved. You can change this in `Tools > Preferences > Editor > Syntax Highlighters`, choose `PHP` from the drop down list and for each attribute, uncheck the `Bold` checkbox.